# What are illustrative examples of how the Sabbath can be broken according to Sabbatarian Christians?

Tags: sin, christian-living, sabbath

I've always heard examples of how the Sabbath is **not** broken, for instance, doing good to others, healing people, etc. However, I noticed that I've never heard examples of the opposite (how the Sabbath **can** be broken).

What are illustrative examples of how the Sabbath can be broken according to Christians who hold to [Sabbatarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbatarianism)?

Comment: I have seen strict sabbatarians discussing (in all seriousness) whether it was 'unlawful' to allow a child to have a nap on Sunday when it was supposed to be working flat out (on a 'day of rest') in religious duties all day long. I look forward to some interesting responses. Uo-voted +1.

Comment: Here is a page discussing forbidden activities https://www.adventist.org/articles/sabbath-observance-1/

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but more generally on the subject of doing work on the Sabbath, check out [these bible verses](https://bible.knowing-jesus.com/topics/Jesus-Healing-On-Sabbath).

Comment: @Nijel How does one speak of Sabbatarian rest on Sunday when the Sabbath in biblical writings is never on a Sunday?

Comment: The [Sabbatarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbatarianism) *wikipedia* article you linked has this: "refraining from Sunday shopping, servile work, playing sports, viewing the television, and dining at restaurants." which links to several articles including [this long document](http://www.epctoronto.org/Press/Publications_JRHughes/The_Sabbath-A_Universal_and_Enduring_Ordinance_of_God.pdf) from Evangelical Presbyterian Toronto Church.  Doesn't this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience, my first realization of what many Sabatarians in the far north of Scotland view as 'breaking' the Sabbath hit me when my husband and I finally arrived at a butt-an'-ben holiday let late one Saturday night. We had traveled a few hundred miles by car, spent a few hours on a ferry, our baby coping better with the expedition than us. This was in the era of cotton nappies. Disposable nappies had yet to be invented. So, when we arrived and unloaded, to walk over fields to the let, we had a big plastic bag full of soggy, smelly, terry-toweling nappies to carry. I only had a few clean ones left. The very nice lady who let the old cottage lived nearby and walked over the fields to greet us.

The second, or the third thing she informed us of, was that, "We don't hang our washing out on the Sabbath."

I was stunned. There were no laundry facilities in the old cottage apart from a big ceramic sink and cold water on tap. So I took the 'command' on board, even though I could never be included in the "We". I soaked the many foul nappies overnight in a bucket, washed them by hand and with warm water from the kettle in the morning, wrung them out by hand, then placed them flat on the sloping grass behind the back of the cottage. The sun was shining on them; there was no wind to whisk them away. Nobody could see them, no washing had been hung out, so I had complied in all conscience with the expectations of our host. Or had I? I doubt if she would have been indifferent had she known.

Further, if I had asked her, "Why didn't you say, 'We don't wash our cars on the Sabbath'?" she would have no answer apart from, "Well, of course that's not done either." Why is it women's work that is picked on for an example of Sabatarianism? (Discuss?)

Another example was related to me years later by a friend who once went to that locality. Sunday came, she and her hosts went to a Presbyterian service of worship. Everyone filed straight out the minute the service ended, hardly talking, and went home for a pre-prepared lunch. All the dirty dishes were plopped into a bucket of cold water, to steep until Monday morning. Then her host said, "What do we do on a Sabbath afternoon? Why, we rest!" And everyone in the house had to go to their respective bedrooms, laid down, and didn't emerge until it was time for the evening service.

So, there are two, true-life examples.

Answer (score 2):

My first experience of of sabbath keeping is similar (in time and place) to that of @Anne .

At the age of about five I was staying in a neighbour's house as my parents were away and sitting on the bed (I seemed to have been left alone for some reason) I was reading a comic.

The lady of the house came in and said 'I don't allow XXX (her son of my age) to read anything but the bible on a Sunday'.

Then she went out and left me feeling guilty.

But I note that she did not stay and read the bible to her five year old guest.

Just left him alone to his guilt.

This, my first ever experience of how (how not ?) to keep the sabbath.

Answer (score 1):

The principal examples of breaking the Sabbath according to Sabbatarian Christians are:

1. Engaging in secular work: Sabbatarian Christians typically refrain from engaging in secular work on the Sabbath, considering it a day of rest and worship. This includes activities such as going to work, conducting business transactions, or pursuing financial gain.
2. Participating in recreational activities: Some Sabbatarian Christians avoid engaging in recreational activities that they perceive as distracting or not aligned with the purpose of the Sabbath. This may include activities such as playing sports, going to amusement parks, or engaging in entertainment that they believe detracts from the sacred nature of the day.
3. Shopping and commercial transactions: Sabbatarian Christians often refrain from shopping or participating in commercial transactions on the Sabbath, as they see it as a time to focus on spiritual growth and worship rather than worldly pursuits.
4. Traveling long distances: Some Sabbatarian Christians limit their travel on the Sabbath to avoid unnecessary work or disruption of the day of rest. They may choose not to undertake long journeys or engage in non-essential travel. This is essentially the principal forming of breaking the Sabbath. I hope that this post can help.

Among the cited authoritative sources are http://wwwbibletools.org

https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/633659/jewish/What-Is-Shabbat.htm#Things

https://www.gotquestions.org/shabbat.html

https://www.gotquestions.org/Sabbatarianism-Sabbatarian.html

Comment: Was this generated by Chat GPT or another AI tool? Whether it was or not, we need you to [edit] this to add quotes or references to authoritative Sabbatarian sources.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to improve.

Comment: How I add quotes.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for this answer. I have formatted your three links so that they can be clicked on to.  However, more is needed, which you need to do, as those sites are so big, specific pages need to be added. If you could do that, readers could click and go straight to the relevant pages. Persevere, do!

Comment: I've placed links to appropriate articles from Chabad and Got Questions.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

There are different varieties of Sabbatarians that may answer the question differently. I serve in the PCA, a denomination that adheres to the Westminster Standards (Westminster Confession of Faith, Larger Catechism, and Shorter Catechism) which address the issue of the Sabbath in some detail in WCF 21, WLC 115–121, and WSC 57–62. Of particular interest to your question are WLC 119 and WSC 61.

WLC 119 reads, "What sins are forbidden in the fourth commandment? The sins forbidden in the fourth commandment are, all omissions of the duties required [for which see WLC 116–117], all careless, negligent, and unprofitable performing of them, and being weary of them; all profaning the day by idleness, and doing that which is in itself sinful; and by all needless works, words, and thoughts, about our worldly employments and recreations."

WSC 61 reads, "What is forbidden in the fourth commandment? The fourth commandment forbiddeth the omission, or careless performance, of the duties required [for which see WSC 58 & 60], and the profaning the day by idleness, or doing that which is in itself sinful, or by unnecessary thoughts, words, or works, about our worldly employments or recreation."

In both questions there are four broad categories of violations: 1) not carrying out the duties, 2) idleness, 3) sinful activities, and 4) unnecessary engagement with otherwise acceptable matters of work and play.

The duties, as defined in WLC 116–117 and WSC 58 & 60, are resting from otherwise acceptable matters of work and play and engaging the whole day in the exercise of public and private worship. Therefore, to neglect public and private worship would be a violation of the Sabbath as defined in the Westminster Standards.

Idleness is not expressly defined in the Standards, and few seem to have offered a definitive explanation of the meaning in its historic context, which has left a lot of room for subjectivity. In his commentary on the Westminster Larger Catechism, Johannes Vos assumes a rather general understanding of "idleness," writing, "Why is it wrong to profane the Sabbath day by idleness? This is wrong because God created us active, intelligent beings. A plant or a tree serves to glorify God by simply keeping alive and continuing its normal growth. But human beings are not plants or trees; they are living souls created in the image of God. God, who is himself intensely active, cannot be honored by human idleness, and especially not by idleness on the Sabbath day" (Vos, *The Westminster Larger Catechism: A Commentary*, ed. G.I. Williamson, P&R Publishing (Phillipsburg, NJ), 2002, 332.). He then goes on to say, "Is it wrong to take a nap on the Sabbath afternoon, or to the a walk in the open air? No. Taking a nap or a walk in the open air, provided they are kept within the bounds of reasonable moderation, are to be regarded as works of necessity, and they may be as necessary to bodily health and mental alertness as to eat breakfast, dinner, and supper on the Sabbath day. Reasonable care of our bodies on the Sabbath is not wrong" (ibid., 332.). The subjectivity of even this seemingly specific answer is highlighted by phrases such as "the bounds of reasonable moderation."

Sinful activities are, of course, more obvious in definition, but often overlooked as a violation of the Sabbath. In its statements on the Sabbath the Westminster Standards make any sin doubly so on the Sabbath by defining it not only as a sin in itself but also as a violation of the Sabbath.

Undo engagement with otherwise acceptable matters of work and play is hard to define in the same way idleness is. Some level of subjectivity is necessarily involved. Obviously, there are really two issues at play here: employments and recreations. These two categories could be thought of as one's productive and playful engagements. The Standards instruct one to withdraw from their productive work, not viewing the Sabbath as just another day to accomplish things. At the same time, it speaks of withdrawing from one's recreation, that is, playful engagement. On the issue of recreations, there is a fascinating historical context involving an ongoing, public, and controversial debate in 16th century Engalnd. J.V. Fesko writes, "By the time of the [Westminster] assembly in the 1640's the fourth commandment had become the center of a pitched battle where politics and theology intersected in a bitter contest over how the 'Christian Sabbath,' the Lord's Day, or Sunday was supposed to be observed" (J.V. Fesko, *The Theology of the Westminter Standards: Historical Context & Theological Inisights*, Crossway (Wheaton, IL), 2014, 284.). In the following pages Fesko goes on to explain how Queen Mary's "Sunday Plays and Games" (1569), King James' *Book of Sports* (1618), and various other writings were shaping the conversation (See Fesko, 285–288.). Exactly how this historic theological conversation gets brought into the 21st century has been an ongoing debate, and the political undertones of the historic controversy are rarely considered. Some ministers, who view playing catch with their children or going for a walk as a violation of the intention of the Standards, take an exception at this point. Others follow the lines of Vos' statements and don't see such things as a violation at all.

In the end, regardless of how one defines "idleness" or "recreations," Westminster Sabbatarians would agree that the Sabbath is always violated when 1) it is viewed as just another day on which one can engage in his regular work to the neglect of public and private worship or 2) one sins on the Sabbath.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange and for this informative answer. You may want to take our Tour:  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour